# How can I build and install openssh server (sshd) with compiler security features

Tags: raspbian, ssh, security, packages

I noticed my raspberry pi's sshd does not seem to have PIE and ASLR enabled. I determined that using the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435038

I'm using Raspbian, is there another OS I can use that enables PIE and ASLR by default?

Is there a way i can rebuild sshd on Raspbian, using apt so that my packages remain sane? I really like the simplicity of Raspbian.

EDIT:
according to goldilocks' comment below, ASLR is enabled already in Raspbian by default. I didn't check in gdb though.

Comment: ASLR is already enabled on stock Raspbian: https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/aslr-address-space-layout-randomization/ PIE is just a stronger version of it (the U&L question you linked does state that).

Comment: @goldilocks well sshd is a piece of software that runs over network, so it could be remotely exploited if it were vulnerable. However, I wonder if having these security features would even matter for a program that runs in a daemon anyways... wouldn't it have the same address each time you make a request since the daemon doesnt restart? if it were to restart or fork, then ASLR and PIE would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take that back about `sshd`; some distros do compile it that way (eg., it is on this fedora laptop).  I was thinking mostly of virus-y things in the system.  I think exploits over a network mostly rely on knowledge of a bug style vulnerability, which doesn't require knowledge of the memory layout, only how to trigger and exploit the bug, which ASLR won't do anything to prevent.

Comment: WRT "wouldn't it have the same address each time" -> Yes, but that's not the vulnerability.  It's about knowing *in advance* exactly where bits of code are going to be in memory.  The fact that a running process remains internally consistent isn't going to help if the layout was ASLR'd because it's not a matter of going through a haystack until you find the needle.  That would never work. You need to know where to look, which ASLR seriously complicates at the very least.

Comment: Well, maybe I should retract that a bit too -- I'm no binary analysis expert, but you can do things with a running binary to try and pinpoint code locations by doing normal things that you know will store something in memory (eg., your IP or some other bit of user data) next to something else, and locate that something else by searching memory for the known thing (the IP or whatever).  That's going to be pretty hard over a network though, because searching the memory of a remote process presents some obstacles.

Comment: And hmmph, having a look here and it seems all of this fedora x86-64 system uses PIE.  I learnt something today...

Comment: Yeah, not having PIE or ASLR is not a vulnerability, they're just improvements that make it harder to exploit vulnerabilities. For example, buffer overflow, or format string vulnerabilities. @goldilocks I may try switching to Fedora then, thanks. That could even be one possible answer to my question if you want to post it.

Comment: There's no guarantee that fedora for ARM (you can't use just any distro image, the x86-64 one will not work) will include PIE just because the x86-64 one does.  PIE executables add overhead to loading (ie., the whole system takes a performance hit); this may be exaggerated on ARM which could be why Raspbian isn't that way.

Comment: *"they're just improvements that make it harder to exploit vulnerabilities. For example, buffer overflow"* -> Not quite right. Yes, they make such things harder, but they also make  *code injection* harder.  Injecting code does not require a bug type vulnerability (it does require privileged access, which a bug might expose).  This is how many viruses work -- they don't exploit bugs, they create them.  Hence dealing with them isn't about fixing software vulnerabilities, it's finding and removing them.  Or making them harder to implement effectively, which ASLR does.

Comment: BTW: Generally speaking, *most* (like 80%+) of the code executed by a process is from shared libraries.  These are compiled with PIC, meaning they are run with ASLR if the kernel supports it, which it does in Rasbian (the link in my first comment gets into how to test for that).  Hence PIE executables make ASLR more complete, but the big deal is actually the PIC libraries.